# About developing with react and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I am planning to develop using react and rails.

Which of the following is common as a way to do it?

1.Use gem called react-rails.

2.Use Rails as an api server.(Separate projects)

Comment: If you have two developers/teams 1 for Rails and 1 for React then having seperate project works better but if  developer/team working on both then having self-contained app is better option. It depends on your personal preference also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way works fine. It depends on how you want to structure your app. If you want a self-contained app, use the `react-rails` gem and everything will be inside of your rails app. If you want separate apps, use a rails api and a separate react app front-end.